# Making Android device a music server

Tags: android, streaming, rtp, http-live-streaming, audio

So the project I'm working on is letting an Android device become a music server. I'm having some trouble on where to start, especially if this is even possible.

I'd like to HTTP Live Streaming, but haven't seen the tools that would allow me to break up the files how I need on Android. The Second choice is using RTP.

Any examples would be great! I've been looking into AudioStream Android native class, but I'm very new to this area and I'm having trouble getting started. I believe I have opened up a stream on my local ip address, but not sure where to go from there.

```
            audioStream = new AudioStream(InetAddress.getByAddress(myLocalIP);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to use a small Http Server that you can integrate into your app and use as a service . Check this http://www.freeutils.net/source/jlhttp/

Comment: Alright, as I'm new to a lot of the web technologies, I'm not sure how I would stream the music from a http server either. I downloaded the jlhttp source, appear to be able to start the server, but I'm lost from there, and haven't had much luck in google searches.

Comment: once you start the server from eclipse using <directory> [port] arguments, start a browser and goto localhost:[port] .You should see the files in the <directory> with their http links.